# Creating and modifying dataframes with a for loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I am new to Python and StackOverflow. Hopefully I post correctly :)

**Problem:** In each for loop I am attempting to create a new dataframe, add columns to it, and fill the columns with data.

**Methodology:** Reading through previous posts, I have learnt I can create new dataframes using "exec" but this is not best practice. Alternatively I can create a dic and modify the df after. Have been trying to use embedded for loops as well

**Issue:** Actually modifying and filling in the created (and empty) df

**Code:**

```
df1 = an existing dataframe with date as its index and profit, tax, and revenue for columns 
#tablelist will only have these 4 values
tablelist = ['QTD','YTD','OneYear','Inception']

# Method 1
for table in tablelist:
     #this works
     exec('{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(table))
     #this doesn't work 
     table['Value'] = df1[profit] - df1[tax]

---> error: 'str' object does not support item assignment

# Output (without line 4)

type(YTD)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

#this works but its outside of the loop so it defeats purpose
YTD['Value'] = df1[profit] - df1[tax]
```

Method 1 does not to help since its outside the loop.

```
# Method 2
d = {}
for i in tablelist1:
    #this works but I cant figure out how add columns and data
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame()

# Output

print(d)

{'QTD': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [], 'YTD': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [], 'OneYear': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [], 'Inception': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: []}
```

Method 2 works but how do I add columns and data?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `d[i]['value'] = df1[profit] - df1[tax]` this should work with second method

Comment: this worked perfectly, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method should be used in python. As the definition is in a clear place. Further the variables are scoped as much as possible. You can easily look for the dataframes which were defined by looking for the keys of the dictionary.
You can add a new column by indexing:

```
d = {}
for i in tablelist1:
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame()
    d[i]['Value'] = df1["profit"] - df1["tax"]
```

The first method creates global variables with the name given by the table array. Therefore if you would like to append new columns. You would not use table as the variable name of the dataframe, but the name given from the strings. Something again with exec. This way I do not recommend as variables are defined as globals, and the way they are defined is very hidden. See following:

```
import pandas as pd

tablelist = ['QTD','YTD','OneYear','Inception']

for table in tablelist:
    exec('{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(table))
    exec(table + "['col1'] = []")

print(QTD) # or others
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the thorough answer and explanation! This really helped me learn the how and why. Thank you for the time!!